# Dodging boxplots and error bars with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, boxplot

```
library(ggplot2)
library(Hmisc)
data(mtcars)
myplot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = as.factor(cyl), y = qsec)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point", shape = 5, size = 2) +
    stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = "errorbar",
             width = 0.2)
```

produces
[image: plot]

**I'd like to dodge the mean and error bars a bit to the right, such that the error bars don't obscure the IQR line of the boxplot.** Specifying `position=position_dodge(.5)` doesn't seem to work, because `geom_errorbar`doesn't know about `geom_boxplot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce a new variable which you use as the x offset for your errorbars:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(Hmisc)
data(mtcars)
mtcars$cyl.n <- as.numeric(as.factor(mtcars$cyl)) + .5

(myplot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = as.factor(cyl), y = qsec)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    stat_summary(aes(x = cyl.n), fun.y = mean, geom = "point", shape = 5, size = 2) +
    stat_summary(aes(x = cyl.n), fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = "errorbar",
           width = 0.2))
```

[image]

The `as.numeric(as.factor(.))` makes sure that the new error bar is spaced at the same position as the boxplots but shifted by 0.5 units.